# Converting a timestamp in R

Tags: r, date, time, timestamp

I am trying to convert a timestamp, such as 2'30"50 to a numeric variable measured in either seconds or ms. I have tried to use separate to separate the variable into 3 variables and then combine them, but it does not seem to work. Does anybody have any tip for how to convert this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two options to get time in seconds.

Option 1 - Extract the numbers from the string, multiply the first number by 3600, second by 60 and third by 1 and add them together.

```
x <- c("2'30\"50", "1'01\"15")

sapply(stringr::str_extract_all(x, '\\d+'), function(x) {
  x1 <- as.numeric(x) 
  x1[1] * 3600 + x1[2] * 60 + x1[3]
})
#[1] 9050 3675
```

Option 2 - Convert timestamp to period object with `hms` and use `period_to_seconds` to convert the timestamp in seconds.

```
library(lubridate)
period_to_seconds(hms(x))
#[1] 9050 3675
```

If you want output in milliseconds multiply the output with 1000.